# Stack with multiple data types

Tags: c++, class, templates, stack

I am trying to write a code in C++ for stack that can push and pop variables of different data
types using class templates.
However, here I am sending doubles in one array and chars in another. I cant find a
way to push different data type inputs into a single arrayso that LIFO functionality is preserved.
How can I push them in a single array ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T1,typename T2>
class Stack{      //stack to hold elements of different data types
    T1 * sptr1;
    T2 * sptr2;
    int top,cap;
    public:
    Stack(){              //constructor
        sptr1=nullptr;
        sptr2=nullptr;
        top=-1;
        cap=250;
    }
    inline bool empty(){
        return top==-1;
    }
    inline int size(){
        return (top+1);
    }
    void push(const T1 & obj){
        if(top==-1){
            sptr1=new T1[1];
            sptr1[++top]=obj;
        }   //if ends

        else
            sptr1[++top]=obj;
        for(int i=0;i<=top;i++)
            cout<<sptr1[i]<<" ";
    }    //push ends
    void pop(const T1 & obj){
        if(top>=0){
            if(top==0){
                top=-1;
                delete [] sptr1;
                sptr1=nullptr;
            } //  inner if ends
            else
                top--;

        }   //outer if ends
    }  //pop ends
    void push(const T2 & obj){      //for T2
            if(top==-1){
                sptr2=new T2[1];
                sptr2[++top]=obj;
            }   //if ends

            else
                sptr2[++top]=obj;
            for(int i=0;i<=top;i++)
                cout<<sptr1[i]<<" ";
        }    //push ends
        void pop(const T2 & obj){
            if(top>=0){
                if(top==0){
                    top=-1;
                    delete [] sptr2;
                    sptr2=nullptr;
                } //  inner if ends
                else
                    top--;

            }   //outer if ends
        }  //pop ends
    void printTop(){
         cout<<sptr1[top]<<" ";
    }
};    //class ends

int main(){
    Stack<double,char> s;
    cout<<"hello";
    s.push('a');
    s.push(5.5);
    s.push(7.77);
    s.push('*');
    s.push(11.01);
    s.push('?');
    return 0;
}
```

How can I change this code so that elements of different data types are pushed in a single array and then can be popped and printed?

Comment: `std::stack<std::variant<type1, type2>>`.  Any reason why you're not using this?  Then you don't need any of that template code.

Comment: because the assignment is to create a stack that can hold 2 different data types in LIFO order

Comment: And that is what I posted does.  Also if you need to write your own stack class, you don't need two template arguments.  A single `T` that encapsulates two values is all you need.  A struct with two members, or a `std::variant`, a `std::pair`, a `std::tuple`, etc.

Comment: @Libra2019 have a look at [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) that Paul suggested. Write your own templated Stack class, then do `Stack<std::variant<type1, type2>>` to have it support two types.

Comment: Someone needs a `union` if the usual C++ solutions are off the table. As a note courses like this basically miss the point of C++ and teach you junk *you should never do* and which does not promote understanding of C++ or programming.

Comment: Also, the stack should be generic -- it shouldn't care what it pushes or pops.  It is the responsibility of the caller to get the item from the stack (in the case of pop) and figure out what to do with it.  In other words, you push a `T`, you pop a `T`, regardless of what `T` is.

Comment: This is how I modified the template:                                                                                     #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <variant>
template<class T1>
class Stack{                                                                                        
                        Then I changed the s instance of class Stack         Stack<variant<double, char>> s;                                                                                      Is this correct? This is giving me error, "Invalid template arguments"

Comment: Put the updated in the post, not in the comments.  Second, [this compiles with no errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/caded8e437bfebfb).